# How to list docker images with their creation date

Tags: docker, docker-image

I would like to list all Docker images on my machine, along with their creation date. Kind of the equivalent of the shell's `ls -l`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--format` option of the `docker image ls` command:

```
docker image ls --format "{{.ID}}: {{.CreatedAt}}"
```

You can also use `.CreatedSince` instead of `.CreatedAt` for relative times.

You can also print repository, tag, digest and size in the same way: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/#format-the-output